# Internal Server Error in yii

Tags: yii

Actually my website works in localhost, why do I get `Internal Server Error` in live?
I have attached my `.htaccess` file here, are there any errors in it?

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    IndexIgnore */*
    RewriteEngine on

    # Make backend accessible via url: 
    RewriteRule ^sysadmin& backend.php

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Did you change the Yii folder reference on index.php file?

Comment: Does your hosting provider allow you to use .htaccess files and if so, do they have mod_rewrite installed?

Comment: "Internal Server Error" is too generic, try to use the most default things that you can, so, will be easier to find out where is the problem. We cannot help to much with this wild generic error message.

Comment: You should look at the error log file of Apache. It will contain more detailed information about the error. Wild guess: It could be that `mod_rewrite` is missing on your server.

Comment: Leave the debug 'on' and see the log file of Yii as well. `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);`
Log file under: `/runtime/application.log`

Comment: Is it Internal Server Error from apache, or Yii? Make sure you have proper error reporting, also check if system works without .htaccess

Comment: I dont know whether it is from Apache or Yii,Iam getting the same error with/without .htaccess

Comment: So it is probably from yii, make sure you have `display_errors = On`, and `error_reporting = E_ALL` in your php.ini. Does simple php file works? For instance with `phpinfo()`?

Comment: yes I checked with simple Php file it works,but my website is not working

Comment: Check the APACHE module `mod_rewrite`, that is what it most likely is

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add the following rule in your htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your apache log. I had same problem, and I checked error log. There was an error that invalid command "RewriteEngine" It means rewrite module is disabled. You must enable it. For linux:

Under Apache 2+ you can simply do:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
or
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```